# Populate struct tm

Tags: c++, c, time, dayofweek, c++-chrono

Is there something in the standard C/C++ libraries which will populate a `struct tm`?

To be more specific about my problem: I want to be able to provide a date and populate the `struct tm` from that (for example: 1-1-2000 00:00:01.) For most of the fields I can just directly insert the data, but I just don't know `tm_wday` and `tm_isdst`.

I'm really looking for a way to populate those two *without* writing some complex day of the week state machine.

Comment: You don't need them in most cases. Ignore them or set to 0

Comment: @ForceBru No, no, I *want* them. I want to output them from my program.

Comment: [`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) is actually specified to perform normalization on the `tm` passed in.

Comment: @T.C. That's so powerful! I had no idea. How does it normalize, that is, which fields does it assume to be correct?

Comment: @JonathanMee it ignores `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`; other values are used to pinpoint the actual point in time the `tm` is referring to, and then the struct members are set accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) sounds like your best bet. The `struct tm` you pass to it need not have values in the specified ranges; it normalizes the fields, including recalculating `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`. To have it attempt to determine if DST is in effect, set the `tm_isdst` member to negative before you call `mktime`.

If you are converting from a string, you can use the [`get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) manipulator to extract the information into a `tm`.

Answer (score 3):

You want `mktime`:

> The original values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the
>   structure are ignored, and the original values of the other components
>   are not restricted to the ranges indicated above.

That is `mktime` can be used as some sort of normalization function that ensures that all fields are consistent, afterwards.

---